# What does this placard mean on some Vienna's buildings?

Tags: vienna

I've seen this on several buildings in Vienna in Innerstadt, a few weeks ago. Wondered what exactly it meant.

[image: vienna placard]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be something used for surveying. The logo on top seems to indicate it's from a [civil engineering company](http://www.kellergrundbau.at).

The scale looks very much like a [level staff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_staff), so it's most probably used for some sort of [height difference measurement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dumpy_level).

I tried to look for projects this could be related to both on the webpage of the [city administration survey service](https://www.wien.gv.at/stadtentwicklung/stadtvermessung/) and the [project website of the construction company](http://www.kellergrundbau.at/news/projekte.asp), however, I can't find anything specific. It could be used for a construction project or to measure subsidence.

Comment: "*It could be used for a construction project or to measure subsidence.*" - More likely "and" rather than "or". My money (as a civil engineer) is on there being a nearby construction project, and they're required to prove that they're not affecting nearby buildings by regularly surveying them for subsidence.